# How to structure imgur type posts

Tags: php, database, layout, structure, imgur

I would like to add image posts to a website much like [Imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZsXY.jpg)

So especially the Image-Text-Image-Text or Text-Image-Image-Text-Image style..

If it was simply Image-Text then I would just have a database table with pictures and their respective captions but this can be any order..

How would I structure a random order of text and pictures in the database while supporting Markdown? A simple push in the right direction is probably enough!

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding the question but...

If you're looking to upload images to Imgur using your own software/php script, you're going to want to use the [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/). You'll have to [Register Your Application](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient) before you can make use of it.

Comment: No I mean a post structure **like** [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/topic/Aww/zuup7), not using imgur.